# The orginal papers/book that Moses wrote of Jesus?

Tags: life-of-jesus, moses

I always posted/stated that the King James bible version wasn't all accurate. What Jesus said is true enough; but man has his thumbprint on that particular bible i.e. Some got lost through translation, and perhaps what they thought was true, scare tactics etc. I know it all isn't facts from common sense as well as other deciphering tools and how God told me/others what/how to recognize the truth of the matter.
 This is not open for debate, its just how it is w/out further ado. My Q is the title, where is the original papers/book that Moses wrote of Jesus? That's the bible I'd love to get me hands on! Thx for any info.Sincerely, Nancy kce~   PSS_I have been saying this for a long time, did anyone else think about this as well?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are disagreeing with. Which manuscript are you talking about that you do not accept ? What 'original' are you expecting to find ? I think this question needs further explanation and clarity in order for it to be answered.

Comment: You are suffering from a severe misunderstanding. Moses lived thousands of years before Jesus and did not write anything specifically about him that anyone knows about.

Comment: @DJClayworth _For had ye believed Moses, ye would have believed me: for he wrote of me._ John 5:46

Comment: 'Moses' often referred to the scriptures in general. Moses wrote general prophecies of the Messiah and you can read them in the Bible. We have no reason to think Jesus is referring to anything other than the scriptures we have.

Answer (score 1):

What you ask for, writings by Moses about Jesus, we do not have, if ever such a thing existed. If it did exist, it would predate by over a millenium the earliest manuscripts we have for any part of the Bible. The most we have is Moses' prophetic warning in Deuteronomy 18:18:

> 18 I will raise up for them a prophet like you from among their fellow
>   Israelites, and I will put my words in his mouth. He will tell them
>   everything I command him.

The ealiest manuscripts we have for any part of the Bible are from the **Dead Scea Scrolls**.
See https://probe.org/the-dead-sea-scrolls/ for the significance of that discovery.

You refer to the King James Version. The Old Testament portion for the KJV was translated from an early version of the Masoretic Text (produced by Jewish sources). It is true that most modern translations are derived from different versions of the Masoretic Text, currently viewed as more accurate. However, even in the areas where they disagree, there are no differences in doctrine. Keep in mind that much of what people claim as inaccurate in the KJV is due to the English Language changing between when it was written and today.

The currently favored versions of the Masoretic Text (and the one used for the KJV) share an incredible property: when compared to the scrolls and fragments found in the Dead Sea Scrolls, which were written during the period 300 BC and 100 AD, there are very few differences. Most are minor spelling errors, word reversals, additions or subtractions of filler words, that do not alter the meaning. This serves to confirm that if the original message was an accurate recording of messages from God, what we have today can be relied upon equally.

Of course, Jesus, when walking on the road to Emmaus in Luke 24, explains to two disciples what the Old Testament said about him, beginning with the Books of Moses. What that means is that the words of Moses contain coded or allegorical references to his life and ministry. This is especially true of the sacrificial system. So in that sense, the whole Pentateuch is Moses' book about Jesus. The Jews had strict practices on how to copy  the Bible to guarantee its accuracy. They did not apply the same level of care to all their ancient writings, but reserved the greatest caution when it came to copying these five books. Thus you can trust what the Pentateuch has to say about Jesus - that is, if you can crack the code.

Also, according to ancient tradition, Moses (or possibly Joshua) was the one who wrote down the book of Job. Job has several dozen prophecies of Jesus. This is a second candidate for your "papers/book that Moses wrote of Jesus".